# Ruby Rack change port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, rack

I have a Ruby web API and using Rack, the `config.ru` file looks like this:

```
#\ -p 8080 -o 0

run App::API
```

It works well, but if I want to change port for web server using `rackup` arguments it won't work. It seems the first line parameters in `config.ru` override the command line arguments. I couldn't find anything on Rack documentation that explains this behaviour.

The question is if I execute Rack server like this:

```
bundle exec rackup -p 8000
```

I expect it to bind to port `8000` but it still binds to port `8080`. How can I change the port without changing the `config.ru` file?

Comment: You're right, the first line changed it. If you want custom things while keeping the default, why don't you just have another `.ru` file without the first line and call rackup with that file instead?

Comment: Hoang Phan, Good point, it makes sense. And maybe I should explicitly say that in my question, I don't want to touch or change the project at all. It's actually packed in Docker image so I wanted a way to override settings when launching the app without altering original image. But looks like I have not much choices :(

Comment: btw, there is a down vote here. Do you mind tell me why did you down vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I decided to submit a pull request for Rack to fix this weird behaviour. Reading the code I realized something very strange, the code should work as I expected :|

It favours command line arguments over config file (`config.ru`)!
Digging into code commits reveals that this changes are not merged into any *stable* version yet (`1.6.4`). It's actually in version *2.0.0.alpha*. Which is obviously not production ready.

Here is the commit: https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/d924f8074e0b3d6c49881c33f983ef323258a941#diff-b578c27b65b1d4a848181b8c1ca082fdL300

So the answer is: it's not possible in 1.x versions and I should either change `config.ru` or forget about that :(